# Connection timed out with own DNS server

Tags: dns, iptables

I recently set up PowerDNS on a server. When I run `nslookup google.com localhost` on the server, it returns

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I also tried `nslookup google.com 192.168.1.100` on my laptop, and it returned the same error message:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I opened port 53, but it *still* didn't work. The output of `sudo iptables -L --line-numbers -n` is

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
2    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

The server is a Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian 8(jessie).

The output of `sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :53` is

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           485/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                485/avahi-daemon: r
```

Comment: is the service running at all, is the listener up? what does lsof -i :53 or netstat -tunlp | grep :53 show

Comment: What DNS provider is the server using?

Comment: The server is using the google DNS server.

Comment: It appears that there was some stray letters that ended up on the end of 8.8.8.8 in my `pdns.conf` file. I can now connect to the server.

Comment: I can't resolve google.com or any other address!

Comment: In any case, it doesn't matter anymore because I wiped and reinstalled Raspbian on my SD card. I installed pi-hole, so not going by this approach anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The `netstat -tunlp | grep :53` result shows that there's nothing listening on port 53. So either your DNS server isn't running or you've configured it to listen on a non-standard port.

Without knowing exactly what you did when you "*recently set up PowerDNS on a server*", or which OS distribution you're running on the server I can't really advise you how to start it.